# Why does this code work and why do we have to increment index twice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am learning how to code Javascript. Been learning for 6 months now. I'm working through code wars problems to help me with my logic when it comes to algorithms.

I was working on this CodeWars problem [Find All Pairs](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5c55ad8c9d76d41a62b4ede3/train/javascript)

Here was my logic and code:

```
  SET a pair count variable 
  SET a sorretd array varible 
  FOR LOOP iterate though the array
  SET index = 0
  WHILE index < array argument 
  Increment index
  IF the current iteration is equal to the index + 1 
  ADD to the pair count varible 
RETURN count variable
```

CODE:

```
function duplicates(array) {
  let pairResult = 0;
  let sorrtedArray = array.sort();

  for (let index = 0; index < sorrtedArray.length; index++) {
    if (sorrtedArray[index + 1] ===  sorrtedArray[index]) {
      pairResult += 1;
      index++
      console.log(index);
    }
  }
  return pairResult;
}
```

The test output I was getting with the two test cases were:

`console.log(duplicates([1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2])) ====> 2`

`console.log(duplicates([1, 2, 2, 20, 6, 20, 2, 6, 2])); ====> 5`

I know it was counting `2`s three times, at least that is what it seems. Anyways, I had to look at the solution. Below is a code that was almost identical to mine that worked.

```
function duplicates(array){
  //Make the magic happen
    const newArray = array.sort((a,b) => a-b);
    if (newArray.length <= 1) return 0;
    
    let count = 0;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length ; i++) {
      if (newArray[i] == newArray[i+1]) {
        count++;
        i++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
```

My question is why are we incrementing the `i++` again within the for loop when were incrementing it already when we declare the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

It's there to avoid over-counting duplicates. As the requirements say:

> If there are more pairs of a certain number, count each pair only once. E.g.: for [0, 0, 0, 0] the return value is 2 (= 2 pairs of 0s)

For example, given

```
[2, 2, 2]
```

you'd want to count *one* set of pairs.

When a pair is found

```
for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length ; i++) {
  if (newArray[i] == newArray[i+1]) {
    count++;
    i++;
  }
}
```

you've now checked off both indicies `i` and `i + 1` - if you proceeded to compare indicies `i + 1` and `i + 2` on the next iteration, you'd be counting the item at `i + 1` one too many.

By doing `i++` inside the loop, you ensure that you skip over to the next unchecked item, without iterating over something you've already checked, to avoid double-counting.

Comment: Oh! That makes so much sense. I `console.log()` the index to try an identify what was happening but still my mind was not able to wrap my head around it. Thank you!